# Advantage of using volume secrets over usual volume mounting

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I was wondering if there is any advantage of using secrets over standard file mounting in Kubernetes. I have to provide credentials, saved on the host machine to one of pods and just cannot understand what are the pros of using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea of using secrets is to reduce exposure and make it more secure. It was specifically designed for this. As per [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/):

- The data in the secrets is encoded (base64)
- Secrets can only be referenced from the same namespace
- A secret is only sent to a node if a pod on that node requires it. It is stored into a `tmpfs` and **not** written to disk. Once the pod that is using the secret is gone, kubelet will delete its local copy of the secret on that node.
- You can set access rights (e.g `644`)
- If there are several secrets for several pods on the same node, one pod will not have access to the secrets of another pod, only the one that it asks for